# Fix the Tag Editor badge description to match other badge descriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, grammar, badge-description

All the badge descriptions on [Badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) page are capitalized as normal English sentences except the **Tag Editor** badge, which says:

```
First Tag Wiki Edit
```

Each word is capitalized in this description, and it looks out of place. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build to "First tag wiki edit" to match other badges.